# Mongoose Schema: Not able to save sub document

Tags: arrays, mongoose

I am trying to save document in mongodb. Don't have any success.

JSON:

```
{
    "ticketType": "Enquiry",
    "type": "AA",
    "subType": "BB",
    "subSubType": "CC",
    "misidnProfile": {
        "serviceTypes": [
            "Postpaid", "Prepaid"
        ],
        "circles": [
            "AA", "BB"
        ]        
    }
}
```

Mongoose Model :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var misidnProfile = new Schema({
    serviceTypes: [String],
    circles: [String],    
});

var taggingProfile = new Schema({
    ticketType: {type:String, required: true},
    type: {type:String, required: true},
    subType: {type:String, required: true},
    subSubType: {type:String, required: true},    
    misidnProfile: {misidnProfile},    
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("TaggingProfile", taggingProfile);
```

Code for saving data:

```
module.exports.createTaggingProfile = function(req, res){
    var taggingProfile = new TaggingProfile(req.body);
    taggingProfile.save(function (err, tg) {
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred',
                error: err
            });
        }        
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Saved TaggingProfile',
            obj: tg
        });
    });
};
```

It is saving taggingProfile but not subdocument msisdnProfile. I am not able to understand where is the problem?

**EDIT:**
Now it is saving. Thanks @Neil
While updating document, I am sending JSON as

```
{
        "ticketType": "Enquiry",
        "type": "AA",
        "subType": "BB",
        "subSubType": "CC",
        "misidnProfile": {
            "serviceTypes": [
                "Postpaid", "Prepaid", "ABC","PQR"
            ],
            "circles": [
                "AA", "BB"
            ]        
        }
    }
```

Strange thing is observed that when i am trying to find document by id, I am getting TaggingProfile object, But it don't have msisdnProfile value.
Check below code.

```
TaggingProfile.findById(req.params.id, function (err, tg) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred',
                error: err
            });
        }
        if (!tg) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'No TaggingProfile Found!',
                error: {message: 'Message not found'}
            });
        }        

        req.taggingProfile=tg;

        if(tg.misidnProfile){
            console.log("## tg.misidnProfile PRofile present");
        } else {
            console.log("## tg.misidnProfile Not present");
        }

        for(var p in req.body){
            req.taggingProfile[p] = req.body[p];            
        }

        req.taggingProfile.save(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occurred',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Updated message',
                obj: result
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: `misidnProfile: {misidnProfile}, ` should be `misidnProfile: misidnProfile,` You appear to be "cargo culting" an ES6 object assignment technique where one is not actually required.

Comment: @NeilLunn, Thanks for update. It is saving now, but not able to update. Now I am updating values for serviceTypes or circles but its not updates.. anything is missing..

Comment: Show the content of `req.body` you are actually submitting. You likely still have a mismatch in the shape of data you are sending to what the schema says

Comment: @NeilLunn Please check updated question